# org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: - dropdown form

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I've looked at other threads related to this error and cannot figure out why I'm still running into this issue. I believe the issue is with my HTML template. I'm trying to create a simple dropdown box to select a list of "workouts" for deletion.

HTML form:

```
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/workout/deleteWorkout}" th:object="${workout}" method="post">
        <select th:field="*{workout}" name="workout" class="selectForm">
            <option th:each="workout : ${workouts}"
                    th:value="${workout.workoutID}"
                    th:text="${workout.workoutName}">
            </option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" class="input-box">
    </form>
```

Controller methods for page:

```
    @GetMapping("/workout/deleteWorkout")
public String deleteWorkoutForm(Model model,
                                HttpServletRequest request) {
    Account account = (Account) request.getSession().getAttribute("loggedInUser");
    model.addAttribute("workouts", workoutService.getWorkouts(account));
    return "deleteWorkout";
}

@PostMapping("/workout/deleteWorkout")
public String deleteWorkout(@ModelAttribute Workout workout){
    workoutService.deleteWorkout(workout);
    return "workoutDeleted";
}
```

Error:

```
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'workout' of bean class [depaul.tables.Workout]: Bean property 'workout' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
```

Any help is appreciated. I'm especially confused because in a different method, I had no problem getting a dropdown box to select a workout functional. Thanks!

edit:
Workout:

```
@Entity
 public class Workout implements Serializable, IWorkout {

public Workout(){
}

public Workout(String accountName, String workoutName, String description, String workoutDate){
    this.accountName = accountName;
    this.workoutName = workoutName;
    this.description = description;
    this.workoutDate = workoutDate;
}

private String accountName;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long workoutID;

@NotNull
private String workoutName;

private String description;

private String workoutDate;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
        mappedBy = "workout")
@Nullable
private Collection<Exercise> exercises = new ArrayList<Exercise>();

public String getAccountName() {
    return accountName;
}

public void setAccountName(String accountName) {
    this.accountName = accountName;
}

@Override
public Long getWorkoutID() {
    return workoutID;
}

@Override
public void setWorkoutID(Long workoutID) {
    this.workoutID = workoutID;
}

@Override
public String getWorkoutName() {
    return this.workoutName;
}

@Override
public void setWorkoutName(String workoutName) {
    this.workoutName = workoutName;
}

@Override
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

@Override
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

@Override
public String getWorkoutDate() {
   return this.workoutDate;
}

@Override
public void setWorkoutDate(String workoutDate) {
    this.workoutDate = workoutDate;
}

@Override
public Collection<Exercise> getExercises() {
    return exercises;
}

@Override
public void setExercises(Collection<Exercise> exercises) {
    this.exercises = exercises;
}
```

Comment: can you share your workout class as well please?

Comment: yep one second.

Comment: What is your workout service returning? a list<Workout>?

Comment: Yeah, i'm trying to just have a dropdown box where have a list of workouts then pick one to delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i think is happening is that thymeleaf is trying to bind the selection of `select th:field="*{workout}" name="workout" class="selectForm">` which is name "workout" to a property of the `public class Workout` which is not part of that class.

Since the actual value that you want to set is the  `workoutID` i would name my field

`<select th:field="*{workoutID}" name="workout" class="selectForm">`

so thymeleaf binds the parameter to the `setWorkoutID()`. instead of looking for a `setWorkout()` of the property that does not exists.

Hope this helps!

Edit 1:

Since there is a @ModelAttribute called 'workout' and of `Workout.class` type expected in the controller, when the page renders, the servlet engine is looking for this object to bind it to the Request. Therefore, you need to add this line to the `deleteWorkoutForm()` method:

`model.addAttribute("workout", new Workout());`

This initializes and binds the object to the Model in the RequestContext.

Comment: thanks for the help. unfortunately that still isnt working :(

Comment: actually no - now its java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'workout' available as request attribute
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:153)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.getBindStatus(RequestContext.java:903)

Comment: What if you use `name="workoutID"` otherwise, since you're not sending the whole Workout object but just the `workoutID` from the select, i would just receive that and create the instance in the `deleteWrokout()` method.

Comment: it's weird because in another form, I have the exact same select layout as in my post and it works fine. the only difference is in the <form>,  the th:{object} is "exercise" (its a form for adding an exercise to a workout).

Comment: I should also note - it isnt even rendering the html page. It throws the error and goes to a generic error html screen. So im not even able to see/submit thr workout.

Comment: okay! let's try one more thing. in the `deleteWorkoutForm()` add this line:

`model.addAttribute("workout", new Workout());`

Comment: Omfg I think thats it. Lemme try.

Comment: YES!! Thank you!!

Comment: Glad it worked! I'll update my answer for further reference!

Comment: Remember to mark this as the correct answer if it solved the problem and is aligned to StackOverflow guidelines

Comment: Done! Thanks again.